# How to connect a remote composer in artifactory to a php satis repository?

Tags: artifactory, satis

I would like to make a remote repository artifactory on a PHP satis repository.

Below is the configuration of the target satis repository:

```
{
  "name": "Satis",
  "homepage": "http://satis.server:48081",
  "repositories": [
       { "type": "composer", "url": "https://packagist.org" }
   ],
   "archive": {
      "directory": "dist",
      "format": "zip",
      "skip-dev": "true"
  },
  "require-dependencies": true,
  "require": {
    ...
  } 
}
```

Under artifactory, in the URL field I put: http://satis.server:48081

In composer setting, I chose the custom option, I tried to put in "http://satis.server:48081" in the fields "Download Url" and "Registry Url" without result.

Sorry for my poor english

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a [remote](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories) [PHP Composer repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PHP+Composer+Repositories#PHPComposerRepositories-RemoteRepositories) in Artifactory pointing to your satis URL - http://satis.server:48081. This repository will proxy you satis repository.
After the repo is created, you need to configure composer to use this repository, for example:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {"type": "composer", "url": "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/composer/satis-remote"},
        {"packagist": false}
    ]
}
```

You can use the Artifactory "Set Me Up" in order to get this configuration as well.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the [terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/jfrog/artifactory/latest/docs) code to create the same. Here we create a remote repository to proxy the satis running as a standalone installation. Try to use the link with one of the service (like `composer require ..` ), then you will start seeing the artifacts getting cached/reflected under the remote repo URI.

```
resource "artifactory_remote_composer_repository" "php-satis" {

  key                   = "php-satis"
  url                   = "https://satis-url.internal"
  composer_registry_url = "https://satis-url.internal"
  repo_layout_ref       = "composer-default"
  vcs_git_provider      = "GITHUB"

}
```

I have tested the code with JFROG artifactory version `7.x` and is working.